# Unable to add language pack from Windows 10 ADK/PE add-on to Windows 10 ISO

Tags: windows-10, dism, language-pack, windows-10-v1809, windows-10-v1903

**Scenario**: I want to add additional languages to the Windows 10 Pro installer so I can easily build Windows instances with `packer` by only changing the `autounattend.xml` file.

I would like Windows 10 to be installed with the desired language during installation, and not by installing it in `en-US` and installing a language pack after installation.

I know I could download each language specific ISO from Microsoft, but I don't like the idea of keeping 4-5GB ISO for each language I want to support when in theory I should be able to create an installer with all the languages I need.

I don't have access to the Microsoft OEM site, the Device Partner Center, or the Microsoft Next Generation Volume Licensing Site.

---

**Resources**:

- Windows 10 ISO: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO
- Windows ADK/Windows PE add-on: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install
- Add and remove language packs, LIPs, and features on demand: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows#add-and-remove-language-packs-lips-and-features-on-demand

---

**Problem**

I've downloaded the Windows 10 ISO from the above public download link, and copied the contents to a writeable location on my computer.

I've also installed the Windows ADK and Windows PE add-on for the appropriate version of Windows 10 I'm working with (1809 or 1903).

When I try to integrate the language pack that's shipped in the Windows PE add-on, I notice that the version does not match the image version from the public ISO.

The language pack version from the Windows PE add-on seems to be `.1` and the release on the public Windows 10 ISO seems to be always `.3`

When I try to integrate a language pack into the `sources\install.wim` of the `Win10_1809Oct_v2_English_x64.iso`, I get the following output:

```
dism /image:C:\mount\boot /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\ko-kr\lp.cab"

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Image Version: 10.0.17763.379

Processing 1 of 1 - Adding package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ko-KR~10.0.17763.1
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081e

The specified package is not applicable to this image.
```

I notice that the language pack version appears to be `10.0.17763.1` while the public 1809 ISO appears to contain release `10.0.17763.379`

If I install the Windows ADK/PE add-on for 1903 and try with the 1903 ISO `Win10_1903_V1_English_x64.iso` I have the same error:

```
dism /image:C:\mount\boot /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\fr-fr\lp.cab"

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Image Version: 10.0.18362.30

Processing 1 of 1 - Adding package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~10.0.18362.1
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081e

The specified package is not applicable to this image.
```

---

There's a load of output in `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` that relates to this operation. I don't know that much about Windows, but it seems like the issue is that it cannot find the parent package of the language pack due to the version mismatch:

```
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  DPX    Extraction of file: update.ses failed because it is not present in the container (\\?\C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\fr-fr\lp.cab).
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  DPX    DpxException hr=0x80070002 code=0x020109
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  CBS    Not able to add file to extract: update.ses [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~10.0.18362.1, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: no parent found, go absent
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~10.0.18362.1, applicable state: Absent
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3140 TID=15264 Package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~10.0.18362.1 with CBS state 0(CbsInstallStateAbsent) being mapped to dism state 1(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_NOTPRESENT) - CDISMPackage::LogInstallStateMapping
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3140 TID=15264 The package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package is not applicable to the image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessPackageChange
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3140 TID=15264 Initiating Changes on Package with values: 4, 7 - CDISMPackage::Internal_ChangePackageState
2019-07-15 16:21:50, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3140 TID=15264 CBS session options=0x0! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
```

---

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to download a Windows 10 ISO from a **public** (Microsoft official) source that corresponds to build `10.0.17763.1` or `10.0.18362.1`?
2. If this isn't possible, are there **public** language packs for the `.3` releases?
3. Can language pack integration into the installer be done without an MSDN account or licensing agreement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because I've figured out the issue.

tl;dr - If you want to customize the Windows 10 installer to be able to install Windows 10 in multiple languages, the Windows 10 ADK/PE add-on is probably not what you want.

Instead, acquire the language pack ISO for your Windows 10 release. The language pack ISO has `Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack` files, which are localisations for Windows 10.

The `Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack` files, which the ADK/PE add-on provides, are language packs for Windows PE. You can use them with the `boot.wim` file, not with the `install.wim` file.

---

> Is it possible to download a Windows 10 ISO from a public (Microsoft official) source that corresponds to build 10.0.17763.1 or 10.0.18362.1?

Yes, the [Windows 10 Enterprise evaluation ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise) for 1809 is release `10.0.17763.107`. The Enterprise evaluation ISO for 1903 is `10.0.18362.30`.

Note that you do have to give "company details" to download the Enterprise evaluation ISO.

---

> If this isn't possible, are there public language packs for the .3 releases?

The issue preventing me from applying the language packs that ship in the Windows 10 ADK/Windows PE add-on is pretty obvious in hindsight:

```
Adding package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack
```

The language pack that the Windows PE add-on installs are, as the name above implies, for Windows PE and **not** for Windows 10 the OS.

If you mount `sources\boot.wim` from the Installer ISO and try to apply the language packs installed by the Windows ADK/PE add-on, it works:

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:F:\Downloads\W10-1809-LTSC\sources\boot.wim

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Details for image : F:\Downloads\W10-1809-LTSC\sources\boot.wim

Index : 1
Name : Microsoft Windows PE (x64)
Description : Microsoft Windows PE (x64)
Size : 1.615.100.044 bytes

Index : 2
Name : Microsoft Windows Setup (x64)
Description : Microsoft Windows Setup (x64)
Size : 1.774.244.896 bytes

The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\Windows\system32> dism /mount-image /imagefile:F:\Downloads\W10-1809-LTSC\sources\boot.wim /index:1 /mountdir:C:\mount\boot

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Mounting image
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.

PS C:\Windows\system32> dism /image:C:\mount\boot /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\ko-kr\lp.cab"

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Image Version: 10.0.17763.107

Processing 1 of 1 - Adding package Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ko-KR~10.0.17763.1
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
```

But try doing that with `sources\install.wim` and it doesn't work because the installer is not Windows PE.

> are there public language packs for the .3 releases?

No, not that I could find. At least not what I would reasonably consider "public"

If you want to apply language packs to the Windows 10 1809 installer, you should use your favourite search engine to look for `mu_windows_10_language_pack_version_1809_updated_sept_2018_x86_x64_arm64_dvd_f17c743a.iso`. It's ~5.9GB large and contains language packs for the x86, x64, and arm64 builds of Windows 10 (17763.1).

I was not able to find a Microsoft official source for this language pack ISO, however some file sharing sites have it available to download. You should be able to find a copy by searching for the ISO name above (at least, for Windows 10 1809).

---

> Can language pack integration into the installer be done without an MSDN account or licensing agreement?

The theoretical answer to this question, at least from my research, is no.

However the practical answer is **yes**. If you can find the above language pack ISO from a third party, you can use the `Windows 10 October 2018 Update` [official ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) from Microsoft to add languages:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Image Version: 10.0.17763.379

Processing 1 of 1 - Adding package Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ko-KR~10.0.17763.1
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
```

I'm not sure what one would do for 1903 or future Windows 10 releases. Determine the name of the language pack ISO and see if you can find a "public" source to download it from ¯_(ツ)_/¯